# Does a developer unlocked Windows Phone 8 device need to be unlocked again if another developer wants to use it for development?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Does a developer unlocked Windows Phone 8 device need to be unlocked again if the original developer de-registers it and another developer wants to use it for development?

I have a developer unlocked Nokia Lumia 620, which was unlocked using my friend's account. Now, I want him to de-register it from his account so that I can use my account to register the device. Is it possible? Is the Publisher GUID associated with a device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i think the regesteration is associated with Microsoft account. so you can register it again with your new microsoft account on the device
  but note a thing : 
After you unregister a phone, apps that you deployed no longer run because the app licenses are no longer valid.

you can know more from this link

[How to register your phone for development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can just Factory Reset the phone and then register it with your account - no problems there. Publisher ID is associated with your developer account, not with device.